# VBA Move data to the left most column

Tags: vba, excel

Suppose you're given this set of data on Sheet1:

```
       A      B      C
 31                 123
 32                  45 
 33                6789
```

(There is a long list of numbers and none of them will be more than 7 digits.)

I want a macro that will have the data show up like this on Sheet2:

```
       X      Y      Z      AA      AB      AC      AD
58                                  1        2       3
59                                           4       5
60                          6       7        8       9
```

Please keep in mind the ranges for where the data shows up on Sheet1 and Sheet2.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub IfBlankNext()
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, LastRow As Long, DestLast As Long, HoldVal As String
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 31 To LastRow
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value > 0 Then

        DestLast = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If DestLast < 58 Then DestLast = 58
        HoldVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
        For x = 1 To Len(HoldVal)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestLast, x + 23).Value = Mid(HoldVal, x, 1)
        Next x
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What does your macro look like so far?

Comment: @A.Franklin That's a great question, haha I forgot to add that in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're on the right track! The column was a little tricky though, since you had to start at the rightmost column, `30`, subtract how many digits a number was, `Len(HoldVal)`, and count up from there by adding `x`. The final code looks like this:

```
Sub IfBlankNext()

Dim i As Integer, x As Integer, LastRow As Long, DestLast As Long, HoldVal As String
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 31 To LastRow
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value > 0 Then

        DestLast = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AD" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If DestLast < 58 Then DestLast = 58
        HoldVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value
        For x = 1 To Len(HoldVal)

            '--- NEW CODE -------------------
            Dim columnNumber As Integer
            columnNumber = (30 - Len(HoldVal)) + x
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(DestLast, columnNumber).Value = Mid(HoldVal, x, 1)
            '--------------------------------

        Next x
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

I ran it here just now and the output matched what you requested. Hope that helps!